# 504 gateway error after node-fetch migration from request library

Tags: node.js, request, node-fetch

This is Javascript

```
    const fetch = require("node-fetch").default;
             let iApi = express.Router();

    
        iApi.post("/update/:name/:value", async (req, res) => {
                   
                    const name = req.params["name"];
                    const value = req.params["value"];
            
                    const headers = { ...req.headers };
                    const url = `${process.env.URL}/name/${name}/value/${value}`;
            
                    const options = {
                        url: url,
                        method: "post",
                        headers: headers,
                        gzip: true,
                    };
            
                    //if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
                      //  options.agent = agent;
                    //}
            
               
            
                     // request(options, function(err, response, body) {
                        // handleResponseNoBody(err, response, body, res, url)
                     // })
                    const response = await fetch(url, options);
                    if (response.status == 200) {
                        logger.info({
                            ...LOG_DEFAULTS,
                            endpoint: url,
                            methodName: "update",
                            description:
                                "update",
                            c_id: req.cId,
                            res,
                            req,
                        });
                        const data = await response.json();
                        res.send(data);
            
                    } else {
                        res.status(response.status).send(JSON.parse(data));
                    }
                });
```

I changed commented lines which used request library and did not have async/await to node-fetch with async and await but now I am getting 504 Gateway Timeout error and I am not sure why, this does not happen with request package though, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: There's a lot of undefined variables in this code (`iHost`, `ec`, `agent`, etc). Please [edit] your question to contain a [mre]

Comment: thank you so much taking a look, I have removed undefined vairables

Comment: I'd be very surprised if you had to set the `host` header. Does it make a difference if you remove that?

Comment: Typically a 504 is a remote problem. The issue is in the endpoint you're calling not being able to reach an upstream service. If you don't control it, there's probably not much you can do